# pattern for consecutive 9 numbers which are same

Tags: regex

Can anyone suggest a pattern format which can be used in react for repeating the same number in 9 times like 111111111, 222222222  & so on..

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could capture the first digit and then repeat the backreference 8 times:

```
/(\d)\1{8}/
```

https://regex101.com/r/H2d8CJ/1